# Probability and Rank of Symmetric Matrix

Tags: probability, finite-fields

Let be

[image]

a $n \times n$ Symmetric Matrix over Finite Field with $q$ elements, where the green color represents 0's and the black color non-zero entries.

How I will be able to demonstrate that probability of the rank should be $2s$ is $1-(1-1/q)\times\cdots\times(1-1/q^s)$?

**EDIT**
Sorry I think that my question is wrong, because I test using python program that formula and that is wrong then I want re-formulate the question: What's the probability of that matrix to have rank $2s$?

Comment: What is $p$? Is it the characteristic of the finite field?

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay is $q$ ... sorry I edit my question ...

Comment: @juaninf: Divide the number of matrices with the required property by the number of all such matrices that satisfy the black/green property.

Answer (score 2):

First consider the rows below s.

It is almost obvious that maximum rank of the mentioned matrix is $2s$, since there can be at most $s$ independent rows below $s$th row and the first $s$ rows will only add $s$ to the rank of $A$.

the probability of the last $n-s$ rows having rank $s$ should be computed (which is equal to the probability of $(n-s) \times s$ matrix having full rank), and then knowing it spans the space, it can cancel out the $s \times s$ square. The probability of the first $s$ rows adding $s$ to the rank is also 1, since the matrix is symtetric and the $n \times s$ matrix that needs to be full rank is the transpose of previous.

for such matrix, looking now columnwise
we need $s$ independent columns in the $n-s$ dimensional space.

Assuming uniform distribution.
For each row not being in the subspace of the previous rows, we have a probability of $1-p^{i-1}$. So, $p=1/q$ is the probability of each symbol

$(1-p^0)(1-p^1)(1-p^2)...(1-p^{s-1})$

so in conclusion the probability of $A$ being of rank $2s$ is $\prod_{i=0}^{s-1}(1-p^i)$.

Comment: What's $p$? If $p=q$ then $1-p^i = 0$ when $i=0$.

Comment: I think that $p$ is supposed to be $1/q$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @mnz I test your formulate using python program and that is wrong, ...

Comment: @juaninf It is a probability, how did you test it? Please explain. If you think this formula is wrong, please mention the point where the argument is not correct. please consider that it is assumed that n>2s, otherwise the probability would be zero.